# Azure Logic App Worflow Integration With Multiple DataBases

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I'm working on azure logic app workflow and I've multiple database (DB1,DB2,DB3 ....) so what basically I need to do make multiple workflows for every database or there is any solution to make single workflow for all databases ?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/logic-apps/

Comment: how about add a parallel branch for the logic app?

Comment: yeah but any other dynamic way ?

Comment: Hi @Faizan Butt, I'm afraid no, there isn't.  Just for now, it's impossible with a dynamic way. May I post it as asnwer? Or do you need wait for more days?

Answer (score 1):

In Logic app, we can add parallel branch for multiple databases.
[image]

But for now, we can not dynamic create the database connection for all your databases.

Comment: Hi Leon ,
How I can add multiple parallel triggers like DataBase table insert trigger ?

Comment: @FaizanButt logic app only support one trigger, but one trigger can add multiple parallel actions/branch.

Comment: Yes I've read documentation properly logic app just support one trigger for now

Comment: @FaizanButt yes. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.